# how to set value of a checkbox using a php variable?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, checkbox

here is my code. I want to set the value of checkbox to be the value I am fetching from the database.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $n=$row['name'];
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" value=$row["name"]>';
    echo $n."<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

More clearly, I am using a query to get 'names' from a database column and I have to use those
names as values for consecutive checkboxes.

Maybe I am not able to explain my problem. I will try again.
Suppose I have a variable $var="abc".
I want to use $var as a value for a checkbox as in;

```
<type="checkbox" name="pqr" value='$var'>
```

In nutshell this is what I want to do, but its not working.

Comment: Please at least try something before asking a question.  A list of requirements is not a question.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What have you tried changing?

Comment: What in your database tells you that it was selected?

Comment: @Notulysses: nope. I have tried to explain my problem more clearly through the edit. please see if you can help. ty

Comment: @user3734204 : Have you got any errors in the error log?Have you checked if data set retrieved from the database is not empty? Information that you've provided can't specify the problem, it is still too broad. And also : what exactly is wrong with your code?In other words : are checkboxes displayed or not displayed at all(skipping while - empty data set) or problem is just with setting the value attribute?

Comment: What output do you have right now ?[Here is an example with the defined variable that is working fine and as expected](https://eval.in/161643)

Comment: @Notulysses: got it. Your answers were correct and are working. thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interpolation (double quoted string) of Associative Arrays in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738850/interpolation-double-quoted-string-of-associative-arrays-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate the value retrieved from the database with the html string like it is shown below :

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" value="' . $row["name"] . '">';
```

Or interpolate variable using double quotes for string definition and single quotes for `input` attributes :

```
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkbox[]' value='{$row["name"]}'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually just missing some quotation marks and a few `.` to concatenate:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $n=$row['name'];
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" value="'.$row["name"].'">';
    echo $n."<br>";
    $i++;
}
```