# error when using variable class name and static method

Tags: php

Running PHP 5.4, so I wasn't expecting this, but I'm encountering the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)
```

Assume you have a variable of `stdClass` setup as follows:

```
$this->variable = new stdClass();

$this->variable->other = array('class' => 'helloworld');
```

Now, assume you want to access a static method of class `helloworld`:

```
// Standard call
$x = helloworld::my_static_method();

// Call with variable class name
$x = $this->variable->other['class']::my_static_method();
```

When calling the above using the variable class name, I receive the parsing error.  What's odd, is that if I do the following, no error is presented:

```
$class = $this->variable->other['class'];

$x = $class::my_static_method();
```

To me this seems very odd, can anyone think of a reason why the class name isn't resolving correctly when using the first example versus the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can anyone think of a reason why the class name isn't resolving correctly when using the first example versus the second?

The PHP parser does not support such a syntax, and that's merely all. This is because the parser has grown historically. I can't give more reason than that.

It will be that with PHP 7 you can see some changes on these syntax details working more into your expected direction [Uniform Variable Syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax):

```
($variable->other['class'])::my_static_method();
```

But until then, you can go around that with the help of `call_user_func`:

```
call_user_func([$variable->other['class'], 'my_static_method']);
call_user_func($variable->other['class'] . '::my_static_method');
```

Or as you wrote your own, by creating a variable:

```
$class = $variable->other['class'];
$class::my_static_method();
```

Or even a variable that looks like something different:

```
${(int)!${0}=$variable->other['class']}::my_static_method();
```

Related Material:

- [Interpolation (double quoted string) of Associative Arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4738850/367456)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Good to see they'll be supporting some more exotic syntax use for PHP 7.

Comment: I won't say the PHP 7 syntax is exotic, even the other way round: it's more consistent then. And I'm glad this has been finally tackled with :)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work (`$this->variable->other['class']::my_static_method()`) as it's essentially using a string as the class name directly. It works when you assign it to a variable first, as it's then being evaluated out as the class name instead.

You can also look into using `ReflectionMethod` invocation in order to call the method, in which case you wouldn't have to store the class name in a variable before using it. Here's the docs on that: http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php and on the `invoke` method (you pass in `NULL` to indicate a static method) http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invoke.php

Here are a couple examples of ways to invoke your function:

```
class helloworld{
    public static function my_static_method($i = 0){
        echo "Here: ".$i;
    }
}

class Foo{
    private $variable;

    public function __construct(){
        //Create a new class
        $this->variable = new stdClass();

        //Create a new property of the class, storing an array
        $this->variable->other = array('class' => 'helloworld');

        //Call function statically
        $x = helloworld::my_static_method(1); //Outputs: "Here: 1"

        //Store class name in a variable before use
        $class = $this->variable->other['class'];
        $y = $class::my_static_method(2); //Outputs: "Here: 2"

        //Using a ReflectionMethod, you can call the function this way, too
        $z = new ReflectionMethod($this->variable->other['class'], 'my_static_method');
        $z->invoke(null, 3); //Outputs: "Here: 3"
    }
}

//Instantiate new Foo class
new Foo();
```

Comment: Interesting - I guess I'm just curious why (in your example) `$class` resolves  correctly, but `$this->variable->other['class']` does not?  In my mind, both variables resolve to the string, `helloworld`.  In your comment, "...it's essentially using a string as the class name directly.  It works when you assign it to a variable first, as it's then being evaluated out as the class name instead."  Why aren't they both evaluated out to the class name?

Comment: It's also interesting, because calling `new $this->variable->other['class']()` works...wouldn't that fall under the same issue?

Comment: So, interestingly enough, when you're using `$this->variable->other['class']` it's being evaluated as a string. Strings don't have a `::` method (i.e. the parser doesn't recognize static method invocation of the string), which is why you need to use a variable (in which case the parser is able to evaluate the variable contents as a class, and the static method invocation works). With your second comment, since you're no longer using static method invocation, `$this->variable->other['class']()` works as expected.

Comment: You can see some info on some of the dynamic language features here (although it's namespaced-base docs): http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php and also the class reference docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php