# php autoload variable class name

Tags: php, variables, autoload

Can anyone explain how this works:

```
${(int)!${0}=$variable->other['class']}::my_static_method();
```

in the answer of this stackoverflow question:

[error when using variable class name and static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29151555/error-when-using-variable-class-name-and-static-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does the same as:

```
${0}=$variable->other['class'];//value here lets say is 'myClass'
${0}::my_static_method();//here now is myClass::my_static_method(); called
```

Why is `(int)!` used?
Because he just tricks around.

Result of `print (int)!${0}=$variable->other['class'];` is `0`.

Because if anything is set here `${0}=$variable->other['class']`,

`print (bool)${0}=$variable->other['class'];` will be `true`.

Then it will be negated via `!`, so it becomes `false` and with `(int)` finally `0`.

And thats the name of the variable that was set before: `${0}`.

But it is very bad practise to give an global variable just an number.

Normaly all variables MUST start with `_` or `A-Za-z`.

Dont know why its droped as example, maybe to make fun of the people.

Dont use this at all!

Just to show how its not done ;)  (working code)

```
error_reporting(0);
define(0x7F,' ..the crazy Girl');
define('§','at? ');
define('_',' Wh');
${'$#?!'} = ' Arrr!';
$♂ = Tom;
$♀ = Tina;
$c = get_defined_constants();
print  _  . § . $♂ .' '.  Just . ' ' .  Want . ' ' . To ." ". Lov€ ." ". $♀ . $c[127] . ${'$#?!'};
//result: What? Tom Just Want To Lov€ Tina ..the crazy Girl Arrr!
```

Feel free to get crazy. :-)

Comment: Thanks. It dawned on me as I read through this how it was working.

Comment: "Dont use this at all!" +1 just for that

Comment: So this will also work in the same way:

    `${'a' . substr($a = $variable->other['class'], 0, 0)}::my_static_method();`

Comment: @Capsland Yes. You substring nothing so you become `a` again. Read this also: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax

Comment: @CapIsland Mark that as answer if it was THE answer you need, thnx

Answer (score 2):

Its a variable variable statement, creating a global variable name using the boolean statement result in the first `${ }`

- `${`

  - Create a variable variable.
- `(int)`

  - Cast result of following statement to integer
- `!`

  - Not statement, invert boolean result.
- `${0}`

  - create a variable `$0`
  - this would normally cause a parse error where a **T_VARIABLE** is expected instead of a **T_LNUMBER**
- `=`

  - set `$0` variable.
- `$variable->other['class']`

  - this is an object variable, defined somewhere else, what it does or what it holds I do not know.
- `}`

  - End of the first variable variable name.
- `::`

  - Call a static method from the class name created by the boolean statement

---

So in Layman's terms, it could create the following statement:

```
$1::my_static_method();
```

Why a digit? Because the variable name is created by a boolean statement, that is either true or false, it is inverted and cast to an integer.
And in PHP `true` and `false` equals `1` and `0`.

So `$1` on failure and `$0` on success.

---

Overall, keep in mind that you are **bypassing** the PHP interpreter for syntax errors. While the feature of variable variables is intended to create dynamic variable names I do not believe they meant it to be abused like this as a result it could mean your code could break with newer versions of PHP. An example would be the [answer of JustOnUnderMillions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39274136/4982088) where the result in **PHP 7** is `What? Tom Just Want To Lov€ Tina Arrr!`

Just saying, using variable variable statements is bad programming practice anyways.

Comment: Thanks. Nice explanation also.