# How to assign a string value to an index of php array?

Tags: php, string

I have the following error;

> Note: Array to string conversion in [file_path] on line 919

which relates to this line of code where I'm trying to assign this string as a value in an array

```
$contents[11] = "$hours:$minutes:$seconds\n$ca_1[remaining_time]\n$h:$m:$s";
```

Why am I getting this error, and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Your questions appears to be ambiguous . Please make it clear

Comment: that is `Note` not error, it seems. it is a literal string or you need to evaluate variables inside that string ? use single quote `'` for literal. one of the variable inside is array. most probably `$ca_1`, use it like alexander suggested, `$ca_1['remaining_time']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bad practice to interpolate string this way because it makes the code very difficult to read, so you should rather use `"{$h}"` instead of `"$h"`.

As **Terminus** mentioned in comments, depending on the PHP version,

```
echo "$ca_1[remaining_time]"
```

Does not necessarily give a

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant

Like `echo $ca_1[remaining_time]` would. But since that didn't work for you, you'd better quote that like `['remaining_time']`.

You might also find some interesting things on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738850/interpolation-double-quoted-string-of-associative-arrays-in-php).

Second, use curvy braces to explicitly tell what you want to insert:

```
$contents[11] = "$hours:$minutes:$seconds\n{$ca_1['remaining_time']}\n$h:$m:$s";
```

This really improves readability.

Comment: Using associative arrays in double quoted strings like: `[remaining_time]` doesn't cause an error whenever I use it.

Comment: @Terminus yes, because it attempts to find a constant with such name, and when it fails, it takes it's string value. That also gives a *Notice: Use of undefined constant*.

Comment: I should've done the full `"$ca_1[remaingingTime]"` That works to access array elements. Php v5.4 and 5.6

Comment: @Terminus, yeah, my bad, ``"$ca_1[remaingingTime]"`` does not give a notice

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$contents[11] = $hours . ':' . $minutes . ':' . $seconds + "\n" . $ca_1['remaining_time'] . "\n " . $h . ':' . $m . ':' . $s";
```

If this still fails, check your variables. Maybe one of them is an array!?

Comment: The PHP string concat operator is a dot `.`, not a plus `+`.