# How to put multidimensional arrays double quoted strings?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I know I can use an array value in double quotation. Like this:

```
<?php echo "my name is: $arr[name]"; ?>
```

But when I use Multidimensional array, I can`t see my result:

```
<?php echo "he is $twoDimArr[family][1]"; ?>
```

Here, the output is: he is Array[1]

What`s the reason?

And I know I can use my code like this:

```
<?php echo "he is ".$twoDimArr[family][1]; ?>
```

But I don't want this.

Comment: Is `family` a const?

Comment: The default representation of array in a string goes one level deep only. So, if you have the items themselves as arrays, it does not go further to parse them.

Comment: Read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interpolation (double quoted string) of Associative Arrays in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738850/interpolation-double-quoted-string-of-associative-arrays-in-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should enclose more complicated structures in curly braces:

```
echo "he is {$twoDimArr['family'][1]}";
```

Answer (score 8):

You should do something like this, using curly braces `{` & `}` :

```
echo "he is {$twoDimArr['family'][1]}";
```

---

See [`String parsing` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) and [echo() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) for more details (especially Example #1) :

```
// You can also use arrays  
$baz = array("value" => "foo");

echo "this is {$baz['value']} !"; // this is foo !

// Using single quotes will print the variable name, not the value  
echo 'foo is $foo'; // foo is $foo
```