# PHP ignoring to check Constant when array index passed without quote

Tags: php

```
$foo=['hello' => "Hello"]; 

echo $foo['hello']; // it works as we are doing in normal way
echo "$foo['hello']";  // it throws T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE error when we use same variable double quote

echo $foo[hello];  // Throwing error Use of undefined constant.
echo  "$foo[hello]";   //  Strange!!! it WORKS because not checking constants are skipped in quotes
```

I am very surprised in `echo  "$foo[hello]";` because not checking hello index as constant. Exactly I want to know reason behind this?

Comment: @Anant, thanks for edition..!!!

Comment: refer..  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4738903/3164682

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's how PHP's simple string parsing works. It's not PHP array syntax, it's *string interpolation syntax.*

Well documented:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.

Answer (score 1):

From manual:

> It works because PHP automatically converts a bare string (an unquoted string which does not correspond to any known symbol) into a string which contains the bare string. For instance, if there is no defined constant named bar, then PHP will substitute in the string 'bar' and use that.

and

> Note: To reiterate, inside a double-quoted string, it's valid to not surround array indexes with quotes so "$foo[bar]" is valid. See the above examples for details on why as well as the section on [variable parsing in strings.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple)

In manual see: [Array do's and don'ts](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts)

Comment: Bare string conversion also produces a warning. This sample here doesn't. Wrong explanation.

Comment: in the section that i've linked it is explained I don't want to paste whole manual here.