# How to get values from JSON decoded PHP multidimmensionnal array ? (PayPal API)

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, paypal

I'm implementing PayPal payments in my website.

The Paypal API sends me the order details through JSON to my success.php script.

I want to get each variable sent and store it in my database.

So I get the JSON data with :

```php
$RAW=file_get_contents('php://input');
```

The data I get looks like this (print_r of $RAW) :

```
{"id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX","event_version":"1.0","create_time":"2019-05-30T09:58:56.756Z","resource_type":"capture","resource_version":"2.0","event_type":"PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED","summary":"Payment completed for EUR 10.0 EUR","resource":{"id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","amount":{"currency_code":"EUR","value":"10.00"},"final_capture":true,"seller_protection":{"status":"ELIGIBLE","dispute_categories":["ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED","UNAUTHORIZED_TRANSACTION"]},"seller_receivable_breakdown":{"gross_amount":{"currency_code":"EUR","value":"10.00"},"paypal_fee":{"currency_code":"EUR","value":"0.59"},"net_amount":{"currency_code":"EUR","value":"9.41"}},"status":"COMPLETED","create_time":"2019-05-30T09:58:52Z","update_time":"2019-05-30T09:58:52Z","links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/refund","rel":"refund","method":"POST"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX","rel":"up","method":"GET"}]},"links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/XXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resend","rel":"resend","method":"POST"}]}
```

I decode it in an Array with :

```php
$response=json_decode($RAW, true);
```

I get this array (print_r of $response) :

```php
Array
(
    [id] => XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX
    [event_version] => 1.0
    [create_time] => 2019-05-30T09:58:56.756Z
    [resource_type] => capture
    [resource_version] => 2.0
    [event_type] => PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED
    [summary] => Payment completed for EUR 10.0 EUR
    [resource] => Array
        (
            [id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXX
            [amount] => Array
                (
                    [currency_code] => EUR
                    [value] => 10.00
                )

            [final_capture] => 1
            [seller_protection] => Array
                (
                    [status] => ELIGIBLE
                    [dispute_categories] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED
                            [1] => UNAUTHORIZED_TRANSACTION
                        )

                )

            [seller_receivable_breakdown] => Array
                (
                    [gross_amount] => Array
                        (
                            [currency_code] => EUR
                            [value] => 10.00
                        )

                    [paypal_fee] => Array
                        (
                            [currency_code] => EUR
                            [value] => 0.59
                        )

                    [net_amount] => Array
                        (
                            [currency_code] => EUR
                            [value] => 9.41
                        )

                )

            [status] => COMPLETED
            [create_time] => 2019-05-30T09:58:52Z
            [update_time] => 2019-05-30T09:58:52Z
            [links] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/XXXXXXXXXXX
                            [rel] => self
                            [method] => GET
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/XXXXXXXXXXXX/refund
                            [rel] => refund
                            [method] => POST
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                            [rel] => up
                            [method] => GET
                        )

                )

        )
    [links] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXX
                    [rel] => self
                    [method] => GET
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX/resend
                    [rel] => resend
                    [method] => POST
                )

        )

)
```

But when I try to insert it in the database :

```php
<?php
$RAW=file_get_contents('php://input');
$response=json_decode($RAW, true);

$sqluser="xxxxxxx";
$sqlpass="xxxx";
$database="xxxxxxxx";

$query="INSERT INTO testpaypal(

        webhookId,
        event_version,
        create_time,
        resource_type,
        resource_version,
        event_type,
        summary,
        resource__id,
        resource__amount__currency_code,
        resource__amount__value,
        resource__final_capture,
        resource__seller_protection__status,
        resource__seller_protection__dispute_categories__1,
        resource__seller_protection__dispute_categories__2,
        resource__seller_receivable__gross_amount__currency_code,
        resource__seller_receivable__gross_amount__value,
        resource__seller_receivable__paypal_fee__currency_code,
        resource__seller_receivable__paypal_fee__value,
        resource__seller_receivable__net_amount__currency_code,
        resource__seller_receivable__net_amount__value,
        resource__status,
        resource__create_time,
        resource__update_time,
        resource__links__href1,
        resource__links__rel1,
        resource__links__method1,
        resource__links__href2,
        resource__links__rel2,
        resource__links__method2,
        resource__links__href3,
        resource__links__rel3,
        resource__links__method3,
        links__href1,
        links__rel1,
        links__method1,
        links__href2,
        links__rel2,
        links__method2
                                        )
                                VALUES(
        $response[id],
        $response[event_version],
        $response[create_time],
        $response[resource_type],
        $response[resource_version],
        $response[event_type],
        $response[summary],
        $response[resource][id],
        $response[resource][amount][currency_code],
        $response[resource][amount][value],
        $response[resource][final_capture],
        $response[resource][seller_protection][status],
        $response[resource][seller_protection][dispute_categories][0],
        $response[resource][seller_protection][dispute_categories][1],
        $response[resource][seller_receivable_breakdown][gross_amount][currency_code],
        $response[resource][seller_receivable_breakdown][gross_amount][value],
        $response[resource][seller_receivable_breakdown][paypal_fee][currency_code],
        $response[resource][seller_receivable_breakdown][paypal_fee][value],
        $response[resource][seller_receivable_breakdown][net_amount][currency_code],
        $response[resource][seller_receivable_breakdown][net_amount][value],
        $response[resource][status],
        $response[resource][create_time],
        $response[resource][update_time],
        $response[resource][links][0][href],
        $response[resource][links][0][rel],
        $response[resource][links][0][method],
        $response[resource][links][1][href],
        $response[resource][links][1][rel],
        $response[resource][links][1][method],
        $response[resource][links][2][href],
        $response[resource][links][2][rel],
        $response[resource][links][2][method],
        $response[links][0][href],
        $response[links][0][rel],
        $response[links][0][method],
        $response[links][1]href],
        $response[links][1][rel],
        $response[links][1][method]
                                        );";

try { $db = new PDO("mysql:host=sqlserver;dbname=$database", $sqluser, $sqlpass); }
catch(Exception $e) { echo 'Error : '.$e->getMessage().''; echo 'N° : '.$e->getCode(); }

$result = $db->query($query);

file_put_contents("post.log", print_r($_POST, true));
file_put_contents("get.log", print_r($_GET, true));
file_put_contents("RAW.log", print_r($RAW, true));
file_put_contents("array.log", print_r($response, true));

?>
```

I get this warning :

> log  PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in
>   /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/success.php on line 57  PHP Notice:  Array
>   to string conversion in /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/success.php on line
>   58  PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in
>   /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/success.php on line 59  PHP Notice:  Array
>   to string conversion in /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/success.php on line
>   60  PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in
>   /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/success.php on line 61 [...]  PHP Notice: 
>   Array to string conversion in /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/success.php on
>   line 87

And nothing is inserted.

What do i do wrong ?

Comment: I would recommend looking at your database design, the idea of storing all of this data in one table isn't particularly good or flexible.

Comment: And literally for all values **quotes** are missing

Comment: Every database (table) field has type and you must provide data in appropriate type to store it. You can't store string in number field or array in...pretty much any field. There's no "array" field type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call your array elements this way:

> $response['summary']

You are missing the quotes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738850/interpolation-double-quoted-string-of-associative-arrays-in-php

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/success.php on line 51

Comment: Then you have to ckeck your quotes of opening and closing the query string

Comment: Thank you that's it i was missing lot of quotes :
$response['summary']
To this :
'".$response['summary']."'

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem :

My query declaration was missing several dots, simple & doubles quotes :

```php
$requete="INSERT INTO xxxxxxxxx.testpaypal(

        webhookId,
        event_version,
        create_time,
        resource_type,
        resource_version,
        event_type,
        summary,
        resource__id,
        resource__amount__currency_code,
        resource__amount__value,
        resource__final_capture,
        resource__seller_protection__status,
        resource__seller_protection__dispute_categories__1,
        resource__seller_protection__dispute_categories__2,
        resource__seller_receivable__gross_amount__currency_code,
        resource__seller_receivable__gross_amount__value,
        resource__seller_receivable__paypal_fee__currency_code,
        resource__seller_receivable__paypal_fee__value,
        resource__seller_receivable__net_amount__currency_code,
        resource__seller_receivable__net_amount__value,
        resource__status,
        resource__create_time,
        resource__update_time,
        resource__links__href1,
        resource__links__rel1,
        resource__links__method1,
        resource__links__href2,
        resource__links__rel2,
        resource__links__method2,
        resource__links__href3,
        resource__links__rel3,
        resource__links__method3,
        links__href1,
        links__rel1,
        links__method1,
        links__href2,
        links__rel2,
        links__method2
                                        )
                                VALUES(
        '".$response['id']."',
        '".$response['event_version']."',
        '".$response['create_time']."',
        '".$response['resource_type']."',
        '".$response['resource_version']."',
        '".$response['event_type']."',
        '".$response['summary']."',
        '".$response['resource']['id']."',
        '".$response['resource']['amount']['currency_code']."',
        '".$response['resource']['amount']['value']."',
        '".$response['resource']['final_capture']."',
        '".$response['resource']['seller_protection']['status']."',
        '".$response['resource']['seller_protection']['dispute_categories']['0']."',
        '".$response['resource']['seller_protection']['dispute_categories']['1']."',
        '".$response['resource']['seller_receivable_breakdown']['gross_amount']['currency_code']."',
        '".$response['resource']['seller_receivable_breakdown']['gross_amount']['value']."',
        '".$response['resource']['seller_receivable_breakdown']['paypal_fee']['currency_code']."',
        '".$response['resource']['seller_receivable_breakdown']['paypal_fee']['value']."',
        '".$response['resource']['seller_receivable_breakdown']['net_amount']['currency_code']."',
        '".$response['resource']['seller_receivable_breakdown']['net_amount']['value']."',
        '".$response['resource']['status']."',
        '".$response['resource']['create_time']."',
        '".$response['resource']['update_time']."',
        '".$response['resource']['links']['0']['href']."',
        '".$response['resource']['links']['0']['rel']."',
        '".$response['resource']['links']['0']['method']."',
        '".$response['resource']['links']['1']['href']."',
        '".$response['resource']['links']['1']['rel']."',
        '".$response['resource']['links']['1']['method']."',
        '".$response['resource']['links']['2']['href']."',
        '".$response['resource']['links']['2']['rel']."',
        '".$response['resource']['links']['2']['method']."',
        '".$response['links']['0']['href']."',
        '".$response['links']['0']['rel']."',
        '".$response['links']['0']['method']."',
        '".$response['links']['1']['href']."',
        '".$response['links']['1']['rel']."',
        '".$response['links']['1']['method']."'
  );";
```

Now it works, thanks for your help !